# Excel Vba - Event Macro Crashes on 2nd Run when used in "Worksheet Events". works perfectly in break mode

Tags: excel, vba, crash

I'm going through a peculiar failure in my excel vba macro wherein the excel sheet crashes on the 2nd run of the macro (Yes, 1st run in perfect).

This macro is to delete all data labels except the recent one for a particular series in all graphs in a sheet. Common graph is used with slicer and Data table to select which line item is needed in graph. on every change in slicer (new line items is selected in data table filter), i want the macro to run and do the label work.

Below is source code for the Graph data label work,

```
Sub Update_labels_Only_To_Last_Data()
    Dim myChartObject As ChartObject
    Dim mySrs As Series
    Dim myPts As Points
    Dim iPts As Long
    Dim bLabeled As Boolean

Application.EnableEvents = False

Name = ThisWorkbook.Name
Set Wb = Workbooks(Name)
Set WsGraph = Wb.Worksheets("Graph")

WsGraph.Activate
    
    With ActiveSheet
               
        For Each myChartObject In .ChartObjects
            For Each mySrs In myChartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection
            
            
          If mySrs.Name = "TAR" Then
          bLabeled = False
            With mySrs
            For iPts = .Points.Count To 1 Step -1
              If bLabeled Then
                ' handle error if point isn't plotted
                On Error Resume Next
                ' remove existing label if it's not the last point
                mySrs.Points(iPts).HasDataLabel = False
                On Error GoTo 0
              Else
                ' handle error if point isn't plotted
                On Error Resume Next
                ' add label
                mySrs.Points(iPts).ApplyDataLabels _
                    ShowSeriesName:=False, _
                    ShowCategoryName:=False, ShowValue:=True, _
                    AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False
                bLabeled = (Err.Number = 0)
                On Error GoTo 0
              End If
            Next
          End With   
                            
           Set myPts = mySrs.Points
           myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowValue 'Add only to last data
           End If
           Next
        Next
     
    End With
 'End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I've tried running macro using a separate button it works perfectly. Then linked this with event macro (Calculation) using below code in sheet (Donotdelete)

Option Explicit

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim Act_Sheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

    Application.Calculate
     If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then 'wait till previous calculation gets over
       DoEvents
     End If

Set Act_Sheet = ActiveSheet
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Call Update_labels_Only_To_Last_Data
Act_Sheet.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

so once a slicer filter is changed, calculate event is triggered using "Count" function in "Donotdelete" sheet and macro gets run. when first time slicer us changed, macro works perfectly. but when 2nd time the slicer is changed to call different graph, macro gets initiated and all of a sudden, completely sheet gets crashed/closed. Tried in break mode and the code works perfectly. tried giving doevents / wait options and still the result is same. To confirm the crash source, tried skipping the "macro" using comment block in eventmacro sheet & the code works perfectly. on any selection change in slicer, macro goes thro the event macro and works perfectly. with this, source is confirmed to be the macro "Update_labels_Only_To_Last_Data()".

i use the same macro in main module and there it works perfectly any number of consecutive times. could not find why it crashes only when used through even trigger and only on the 2nd time !!!. did all my google help thing for couple of weeks now but no result. see if you guys can show me a wayout.

Comment: What is the error message and which line does it crash on?

Comment: No error message and when i step through using F8,  it works perfectly fine. Also, during the first click in slicer filter, the macro works and does the job as intended. When i click the 2nd time in slicer, macro starts and then excel gets closed in few seconds.